# Azure Functions Core Tools throwing error with default function: can't find ../azurefunctions/functions.js

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I reinstalled Windows 10 several weeks back and had to reinstall all the tools. Not being a professional, I just went with the latest versions of everything and today updated the Core Tools.

I'm currently at

- Node: 8.11.1
- Core Tools: 1.0.11

I just created a new function app and function and am getting the following error when I try to call the URI through Postman.

```
{
    "id": "53b6098d-69e4-45a1-9f0f-2bec6f965435",
    "requestId": "ca41a391-35ca-440f-a78b-007473b9ee5a",
    "statusCode": 500,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "message": "Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerJS -> One or more errors occurred. -> Error: Cannot find module '../azurefunctions/functions.js'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)\n    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)\n    at eval (eval at compileFunc (C:\\Users\\giraffeslacks\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-core-tools\\bin\\edge\\double_edge.js:34:28), <anonymous>:1:23)\n    at compileFunc (C:\\Users\\giraffeslacks\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-core-tools\\bin\\edge\\double_edge.js:35:16)",
    "errorDetails": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerJS ---> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. ---> Error: Cannot find module '../azurefunctions/functions.js'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)\n    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)\n    at eval (eval at compileFunc (C:\\Users\\giraffeslacks\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-core-tools\\bin\\edge\\double_edge.js:34:28), <anonymous>:1:23)\n    at compileFunc (C:\\Users\\giraffeslacks\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-core-tools\\bin\\edge\\double_edge.js:35:16)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at EdgeJs.Edge.Func(String code)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.NodeFunctionInvoker.get_GlobalInitializationFunc()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.NodeFunctionInvoker.InitializeAsync()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.NodeFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnType](TReflected instance,Object[] arguments)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception : Error: Cannot find module '../azurefunctions/functions.js'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)\n    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)\n    at eval (eval at compileFunc (C:\\Users\\giraffeslacks\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-core-tools\\bin\\edge\\double_edge.js:34:28), <anonymous>:1:23)\n    at compileFunc (C:\\Users\\giraffeslacks\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-core-tools\\bin\\edge\\double_edge.js:35:16)<---\r\n \r\n   End of inner exception\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ExceptionDispatchInfoDelayedException.Throw()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.CallAsync(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost.CallAsync(String method,Dictionary`2 arguments,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostManager.HandleRequestAsync(FunctionDescriptor function,HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Host.FunctionRequestInvoker.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken,WebScriptHostManager scriptHostManager,WebHookReceiverManager webHookReceiverManager)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.HttpRequestManager.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,Func`3 processRequestHandler,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.WebScriptHostHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.SystemTraceHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a bug on the latest v1.0.11 function core tool.

I install it using npm on my side, and reproduce the error after triggering a 
js httptrigger(template).

The error seems to occur only when using js trigger, as I create a js blobtrigger same error occurs. For c#, test on httptrigger and blobtrigger, both work.

I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/446) on github and waited for Azure team's reply.

Comment: Great. Thanks. It also happened with v1.0.10 which is the version that was originally installed on my system.

Comment: I just pushed 1.0.12 with the fix. Sorry about the break

Comment: @ahmelsayed, test it just now, works well. Thanks a lot for your quick response.